# fetch company name in all the pages using selenium java(by clicking on next button)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to ftech all the company name by clciking on all the page.

here is my sample code:

```
@Test(priority=2)
public void fetchdata() {
    java.util.List<WebElement> companyname = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/h3/a/div"));
    for (WebElement comapany : companyname) {
        System.out.println(comapany.getText());
    }
    boolean nextbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Next']")).isEnabled();
    
    if (nextbutton == true) {
        WebElement next = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Next']"));
        next.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this one should work according to your needs.

```
    List<WebElement> companyname = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/h3/a/div"));
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        
    for (WebElement company: companyname) 
    {
        names.add(company.getText());
    }
    
    boolean nextbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Next']")).isEnabled();
    String btnNextClassName = nextbutton.getAttribute("class");
        
    while(!btnNextClassName.contains("disabled"))
    {
       nextbutton.click();
       companyname = companyname;
    
       for (WebElement company: companyname) 
       {
          names.add(company.getText());
       }
    }
            
    for(String n : names)
    {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
    int totalNames = names.size();
    System.out.println(totalNames);
```